# From a dataframe using the apply() method, how to return a new column with lists of elements from the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

There's an operation that is a little counter intuitive when using pandas apply() method. It took me a couple of hours of reading to solve, so here it is.

So here is what I was trying to accomplish.

I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'one': [[2],['test']], 'two': [[5],[10]]})
      one   two
0     [2]   [5]
1  [test]  [10]
```

and I want to add the columns per row to create a resulting list of length = to the DataFrame's original length like so:

```
def combine(row):
    result = row['one'] + row['two']
    return(result)
```

When running it through the dataframe using the apply() method:

```
test.apply(lambda x: combine(x), axis=1)
    one  two
0     2    5
1  test   10
```

Which isn't quite what we wanted. What we want is:

```
       result
0      [2, 5]
1  [test, 10]
```

**EDIT**

I know there are simpler solutions to this example. But this is an abstraction from a much more complex operation.Here's an example of a more complex one:

df_one:

```
    org_id     date       status     id
0     2     2015/02/01     True      3
1     10    2015/05/01     True      27
2     10    2015/06/01     True      18
3     10    2015/04/01     False     27
4     10    2015/03/01     True      40
```

df_two:

```
    org_id      date
0     12     2015/04/01
1     10     2015/02/01
2     2      2015/08/01
3     10     2015/08/01
```

Here's a more complex operation:

```
def operation(row, df_one):
    sel = (df_one.date < pd.Timestamp(row['date'])) & \
          (df_one['org_id'] == row['org_id'])
    last_changes = df_one[sel].groupby(['org_id', 'id']).last()
    id_list = last_changes[last_changes.status].reset_index().id.tolist()

    return (id_list)
```

then finally run:

```
    df_one.sort_values('date', inplace=True)

    df_two['id_list'] = df_two.apply(
        operation,
        axis=1,
        args=(df_one,)
    )
```

This would be impossible with simpler solutions. Hence my proposed one below would be to re write `operation` to:

```
def operation(row, df_one):
    sel = (df_one.date < pd.Timestamp(row['date'])) & \
          (df_one['org_id'] == row['org_id'])
    last_changes = df_one[sel].groupby(['org_id', 'id']).last()
    id_list = last_changes[last_changes.status].reset_index().id.tolist()

    return pd.Series({'id_list': id_list})
```

We'd expect the following result:

```
    id_list
0     []
1     []
2     [3]      
3     [27,18,40]
```

Comment: What is the type of your date columns in your two dataframes? E.g. string, timestamp, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't the last row be `[18, 27, 40]`?

Comment: or `[27, 18, 40]` since row 1 in `df_one` appears to satisfy the criteria and comes before row 2.

Comment: Yes! you're absolutely right. Good catch! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this problem lies in how `pandas.apply()` method works.

When defining

```
def combine(row):
    result = row['one'] + row['two']
    return(result)
```

the function will be returning a list for each row that gets passed in. This is a problem if we use the function with the `.apply()` method because it will interpret the resulting lists as a Series where each element is a column of that same row.

To solve this we need to create a Series where we specify a new column name like so:

```
def combine(row):
    result = row['one'] + row['two']
    return pd.Series({'result': result})
```

And if we run this again:

```
test.apply(lambda x: combine(x), axis=1)
       result
0      [2, 5]
1  [test, 10]
```

We'll get what we originally wanted! Again, this is because we are forcing pandas to interpret the entire result as a column.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC we can simply sum two columns:

```
In [93]: test.sum(axis=1).to_frame('result')
Out[93]:
       result
0      [2, 5]
1  [test, 10]
```

because when we sum lists:

```
In [94]: [2] + [5]
Out[94]: [2, 5]
```

they are getting concatenated...

Comment: this is true. But my example is an abtraction of a much more complex operation that wouldn't be possible with your solution. It would be however possile with my solution.